Can peanuts be used as green manure in tropical climates if the nuts are not removed?
Are peanut plants (Arachis hypogaea) suitable as green manure in tropical climates? I have two related concerns:

The lack of winter frost in tropical climates means that peanuts could grow all year round. If I fail to completely remove all nuts when I incorporate the peanut plants into the soil as green manure, I am worried that the nuts may eventually become grow into a plant that would be a nuisance to whatever plants I grow afterwards. Is this a valid concern?

If I do not intend to consume the underground parts of the peanut plant, can I till the entire plant into the soil? In terms of nutrients for the soil, are the underground parts suitable as green manure too? (Also, similar to concern #1 above, I am worried that incorporating the entire plant into soil could cause new peanut plants to germinate and become a weed).




If growing the peanuts for harvest, you'd be removing the nuts. If
you're careless when doing that, you might have to pull a few out as
soon as they come up. Peanuts are not bindweed, so that should be all that's needed. Or you could shred the root portions of the
plants before tilling them in to destroy the seeds you may have missed.
As with other "green manures" that are grown to be tilled into the soil, till them in before they
make viable seeds to prevent them becoming a weed.


How do I determine when to till in the peanut plants, given that the seeds are underground?

Look at a calendar. Given a ripening time of 130-180 days, https://nationalpeanutboard.org/news/how-to-grow-peanuts-at-home/ tilling them in at 90-100 days should be safe.

For a more paranoid approach, you could till them under when they flower, but that might be only 40-45 days. Which then starts to beg the question of "perhaps a more suitable green manure exists, if you have no interest in them other than as a green manure?"

"perhaps a more suitable green manure exists, if you have no interest in them other than as a green manure?" — Could Arachis repens be more suitable than Arachis hypogaea in my case?
